# SpriteKit app crashing on iPhone within 2 weeks

Tags: crash, sprite-kit

I have developed a game using SpriteKit. When I install it on my iPhone, it works perfectly. I repeatedly play the game several times. Then, around 2 weeks in, when tapping on my app to open it, I get a message "[Game] is no longer available". I am then forced to reinstall the app on my iPhone.

What would cause my app to crash in this way? Have I neglected to put in code that would prevent the app from crashing when it is idle? Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Without a paid developer account, you can only install an app on one of your devices for a fairly short amount of time (I think 1 week, but perhaps 2).  After that you have to reinstall it.